# Can the Sprint Burndown use PBI Effort instead of Task Effort?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have Feature and PBIs with Effort set using Story Points but the Sprint Burndown only shows what looks lie the time Effort of the Tasks.
This is not that useful as it is the Story points of the PBIs or even Features that we wish to use

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in TFS burndown it according your Tasks, not the PBIs, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/sprint-burndown-scrum?view=azure-devops-2020#data-in-the-report) more info.

In Azure DevOps Server 2019 and above you can add burndown chart according to Story Points:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets

There was in the past an extension [Real Sprint burndown](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomkamphuis.vsts-extensions-myExtensions&ssr=false#qna) that is a chart for people using story point estimations per PBI, but I see now it's unpublished from the Marketplace.

You can go to his [GitHub](https://github.com/tomkamphuis/VSODashboardRealBurndown) and try to build it and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Not very useful as a feature, this will cause upset as devs will now have to also supply estimates on Tasks in Hours. JIRA actually is configurable from what I remember, definitely can use Story Points.

Comment: @learnerplates I updated my answer: In Azure DevOps Server 2019 and above you can add burndown chart according to Story Points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets

Comment: Thank you. We may get this version next year, we're on the Server version: Azure DevOps Server
Version Dev17.M153.5